# What's the difference between using the packageS ROCR and pROC when plotting curve and calculating AUC?

Tags: r

I am a little confused when using the package ROCR. I don't quite understand how it works compare with the pROC package which seems more intuitive for me.

compare the command of the 2 packages:

[image: ROCR Call vs. pROC Call]

Comment: In general, it is good to put the code in a code block and not an image.

Comment: This might be a better fit for https://stats.stackexchange.com